# Google Rich Snippet - Display product image

Tags: magento, seo, microdata

I am currently trying to implement microdatas (schema.org) in my Magento website, and I still have a question not finding answer. How can I display product image in Google Search results ?

I know I can implement product microdatas, but yet the google tester doesn't seem to display images (as it does with cook articles, for example).

Is it possible ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google supports product image in the organic results yet.

You may be thinking of the Google Shopping results. It sometimes gets to display product images alongside the normal search results. To find out more go here:

http://www.google.com.au/merchants

You need to provide a feed of all your products and you will probably have to pay via AdWords to get listings now.